# Get user's session outside of Facebook Application from a windows service or desktop app

Tags: c#, apache-flex, facebook

I've a flash facebook application, i can take the session info from flash client and send the session information to server.

I need to check if the user connected to the server via facebook application or not. That's why i need to get the user's session from facebook page directly by my server.

How can i do it? I use C# for all database and communication system. Flash interface does only application responsibilities.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this. You must use Facebook OAuth authentication. If you want to use the user's session after they are not using your application then you should ask for the "offline_access" extended permission. If you have that permisssion, you will get an access token that never expires. Then you can save that access token in your database and use it from you windows service. Check out the [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com) to make all this stuff a lot easier.

Comment: with a php website it is easy to get the session [i've used FBML and it goes really fast and easy]